# Use nmcli without X interface

Tags: networkmanager, nmcli

I have a xubuntu virtual machine, when it's booted to xfce4, I connect to it via SSH.

When I try to use nmcli, it complains:

```
%> nmcli con up myvpn
Error: Connection activation failed: Not authorized to control networking.
```

Anyone know how to fix that? I've tried to setup some environment variables, like `XAUTHORITY` or `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`, I don't know what's missing here.

**EDIT**

It works with `sudo`, but now I got another problem

```
Error: Connection activation failed: no valid VPN secrets
```

I don't use gnome keychain, but seems like root user can't read the plain text password

Comment: Does this work when you connect as root instead of a normal user?

Comment: @dhag I got another problem with vpnsecrets ..

Comment: Since the machine has xfce4 installed then SSH can run xauth, so you can connect with `ssh -Y` and that will generate `.Xauthority` for you.  On other other hand I do not think XAUTH has anything to do with `nmcli`.  What does the network file under `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` actually contains?

Comment: @grochmal eth0 and myvpn

Comment: In case anyone finds this old question: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39203457/495319 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/681708/comments/11